# Unfold or close content in html/JS - Need display partial content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to display partial content, then unfold or close the remaining content in html/JS,

I have project.html as below, what I achieved is as attached picture, it doesn't display anything before I clicked:
[image]
[image]

```
<style type="text/css">  
#box4{padding:10px;border:1px solid green;}   
</style>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
function openShutManager(oSourceObj,oTargetObj,shutAble,oOpenTip,oShutTip){  
var sourceObj = typeof oSourceObj == "string" ? document.getElementById(oSourceObj) : oSourceObj;  
var targetObj = typeof oTargetObj == "string" ? document.getElementById(oTargetObj) : oTargetObj;  
var openTip = oOpenTip || "";  
var shutTip = oShutTip || "";  
if(targetObj.style.display!="none"){  
   if(shutAble) return;  
   targetObj.style.display="none";  
   if(openTip  &&  shutTip){  
    sourceObj.innerHTML = shutTip;   
   }  
} else {  
   targetObj.style.display="block";  
   if(openTip  &&  shutTip){  
    sourceObj.innerHTML = openTip;   
   }  
}  
}  
</script>  


   <div><button onclick="openShutManager(this,'box4',false,'点击关闭','点击展开')">点击展开</button></div>
    <div class="list-group list-group-flush list-group-formset">
      <div class="col-10" id="box4" style="display:none">{% for c in course %}<a href="{% url 'supervisors:course_change' c.pk %}">{{ c }}</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{% endfor %}</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could play with the `text-overflow: ellipsis`so in your collapsed item you should set a class with the following properties

```
.collapsed-content {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```js
function openShutManager(oSourceObj,oTargetObj,shutAble,oOpenTip,oShutTip){  
var sourceObj = typeof oSourceObj == "string" ? document.getElementById(oSourceObj) : oSourceObj;  
var targetObj = typeof oTargetObj == "string" ? document.getElementById(oTargetObj) : oTargetObj;  

  targetObj.classList.toggle("collapsed-content");

  if(targetObj.classList.contains("collapsed-content")){  
    sourceObj.innerHTML = oShutTip;   
  } else {  
    sourceObj.innerHTML = oOpenTip;   
  }  
}
```

```css
#box4{padding:10px;border:1px solid green;}
.collapsed-content {

  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div><button onclick="openShutManager(this,'box4',false,'点击关闭','点击展开')">点击展开</button></div>
    <div class="list-group list-group-flush list-group-formset">
      <div class="col-10 collapsed-content" id="box4">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis tortor orci. Vestibulum elementum leo augue, quis accumsan justo consequat in. Pellentesque egestas sollicitudin velit, sed consequat massa lobortis vitae. Integer aliquet arcu eros, id bibendum diam sodales pulvinar. Aenean odio tellus, venenatis a rutrum a, interdum eu turpis. Ut condimentum volutpat aliquam. Praesent auctor ex nec sagittis commodo.
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much, I wrote javascript in project.html, could you please show me where I need to place those code?

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you so much, did you find the word on that button? it always display`点击展开`(it means click to unfold), `点击关闭`(click to close) disappeared

Comment: I've just replaced whole the content of your javascript function with the class toggler. Now I've added that, please check the words are correct and accept the answer if that helped you! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so so so much, it works fine now, I already accept the answer, thank you again @jmtalarn