# How to display partial words one line for one object, moving mouse pointer over the text fields display full text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The pages displayed partial content by [unfold or close the remaining content in html/JS by this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50853706/unfold-or-close-content-in-html-js-need-display-partial-content)(page alreay had a unfold or close function in box), now I would like to display the partial title of those contents of box, pic and list.html of page are as below.

The long green words in red box are title of contents, every title are too long to read, so I would like to display them one line for one object and moving mouse pointer over the text fields will display the full text.

If I use the code as below, the function of unfold or close of box will fail, and moving mouse pointer over the text fields doesn't display full text, not whole text.

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
#box1,#box2,#box3,#box4,#box5,#box6{padding:12px;border:0px solid green;}
.collapsed-content {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.expanded-content {
  display: block;
}

p{
display:inine-block;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
max-width: 100px;

}

p:hover{
overflow:visible;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openShutManager(oSourceObj,oTargetObj,shutAble,oOpenTip,oShutTip){
var sourceObj = typeof oSourceObj == "string" ? document.getElementById(oSourceObj) : oSourceObj;
var targetObj = typeof oTargetObj == "string" ? document.getElementById(oTargetObj) : oTargetObj;

  //targetObj.classList.toggle("expanded-content");
  targetObj.classList.toggle("collapsed-content");
  if(targetObj.classList.contains("collapsed-content")){
    sourceObj.innerHTML = oShutTip;
  } else {
    sourceObj.innerHTML = oOpenTip;
  }
}
</script>


  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10">
          <strong>学过的课程列表</strong>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="list-group list-group-flush list-group-formset">
      <div class="col-10 collapsed-content" id="box3" style="word-break: break-all;">
      {% for c in course %}
      <p class="hide"><a href="{% url 'supervisors:course_change' c.pk %}">{{ c }}</p></a>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div><button onclick="openShutManager(this,'box3',false,'点击关闭','点击展开')">点击展开</button></div>
      <div class="card-footer">
       </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Tell me if the answer given is what you desire

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any green text. Assuming your bold text needs to be truncated when not hovering on, you only need css for this:

```css
.card-header .col-10 {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.card-header .col-10:hover {
    overflow: initial;
    white-space: initial;
    text-overflow: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10">
          <strong>chinese text chinese text chinese text chinese text chinese text chinese text chinese text chinese text chinese text chinese text chinese text chinese text chinese text </strong>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="list-group list-group-flush list-group-formset">
      <div class="col-10 collapsed-content" id="box3" style="word-break: break-all;">
      {% for c in course %}
      <a href="{% url 'supervisors:course_change' c.pk %}">{{ c }}</a>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div><button onclick="openShutManager(this,'box3',false,'点击关闭','点击展开')">点击展开</button></div>
      <div class="card-footer">
       </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, the long green words in red box are title of contents, every title are too long to read, so I would like to display them one line for one object,  and moving mouse pointer over the text fields will display the full text. Do I need javascript? I thought it needs mouse pointer function?

Comment: Hi, I pasted a demo here, could you please help me to review it? Thank you so much  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51202142/how-to-unfold-or-close-content-line-by-line-in-html-js-6-for-loops

Answer (score 0):

OK so another answer

for suppose

```css
p{
display:inine-block;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
max-width: 100px;

}

p:hover{
overflow:visible;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="hide">
<p>qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can set the max width accordingly to display one line
I hope this works

Comment: Hi, if I moved mouse pointer over the text fields, will it display the full text?

Comment: Yeah use the run code snippet button to check it does

Comment: Thank you again for your patience, because page already had a unfold or close function in box, If I use the code as above you wrote, the function of unfold or close of box will fail(it've worked well before), and about new function, moving mouse pointer over the text fields doesn't display full text, it display partial title, not whole title, our titles are really long.

Comment: Hi @AshAR, really need you help, thank you so much, you code works well here, I updated my questions and code, those code need to be placed into another class which already had a unfold or close function in box, I just can't let both of them work......

Comment: Hi, I pasted a demo here, could you please help me to review it? Thank you so much  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51202142/how-to-unfold-or-close-content-line-by-line-in-html-js-6-for-loops

Comment: I'll do it for sure but i am a lil bit bussy these days if u could wait till the upcoming wednesday

Comment: Thank you so much, take your time please.