# How to fold/unfold (close/open) content line-by-line in html/JS - 6 `for loops`

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop

I would like to use code as below in my projects, I have 6 object lists to hide and show, do I need define 6 ids of boxes?(I would like to single control those 6 ids with `Hide` and `Show` function) And the content of box in demo "Some texts. Some texts. Some texts." are all in `for loop`, can I display the full textfield of that `for loop`? Because the text is too long, and they will go out of the screen.

In addition, can I set `Hide` to the default value, the code as below will display contents of `for loop` whatever I changed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .box p {
      width: 360px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .box p:hover {
      overflow: visible;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="statusChange">Show</button>
  <div class="box" id="box">
    <p>1、Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. </p>
    <p>2、Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts.</p>
    <p>3、Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts.</p>
    <p>4、Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts. Some texts.</p>
    <p>5、......</p>
  </div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('statusChange').onclick = function() {
      var text = this.innerText
      if (text == 'Hide') {
        document.getElementById('box').style.cssText = 'display:none'
        this.innerText = 'Show'
      } else if (text == 'Show') {
        document.getElementById('box').style.cssText = 'display:block'
        this.innerText = 'Hide'
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not too clear as to your requirements.  But if you want to display content one by one, then bootstrap tabs and pills may help. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp

Comment: I would like to display content one by one like my code on the snippet, but I have 6 lists of those content, and they are 6 `for loops`, I was trapped about single control of `Show` and `Close`

Comment: @T.Shah I read the link about bootstrap tabs and pills, I don't need table or pills one by one, I would like the function of `Hide` content, and `Show` content display partial words one line for one object, moving mouse pointer over the text fields display full text, just like my sample code